# resharper is not ignoring tests marked with Category Attribute in XUnit

Tags: resharper, xunit.net

having:

```
[Category("Contract")]
public class ProgramClientShould
{
}
```

or:

```
[Trait("Contract", null)]
public class ProgramClientShould
{
}
```

and Resharper -> Options -> Tools -> Unit Testing:
"Skip tests from categories" with value "Contract"

Still, tests in ProgramClientShould are executed. What's wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

xunit doesn't have a `Category` attribute, so the resharper runner won't recognise that. As for the trait attribute, you need to provide a value, then filter for something in the format `key[value]`. E.g. if you want to use `[Trait("Owner", "Matt")]`, you would filter for a category of `Owner[Matt]`.

The trait key `Category` is treated differently, and just the value is used, so `[Trait("Category", "integration")]` would use `integration` as the category filter in the resharper options.

Comment: Your answer suggest that the ReSharper test runner is actually able to display custom traits (like `[Trait("Owner", "Matt")]`). It seems that this is not the case (in ReSharper Ultimate 2017.3.1). The only thing that ReSharper understands is the Category key (`[Trait("Category", "Foo")]`)

Comment: Yes, this appears to be a change in behaviour - it now only displays "category" traits. I don't know if it's a deliberate change or a regression. I've asked internally.

Comment: This may be the bug related to it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-458779